# Not getting the values in to mail

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, post

I have created a dynamic drop down list add row in the form with using java script. In my form i m not getting the value from this. If we fill 3 rows getting only one row value to mail.

I have changed the code now getting values but not able to submit to email
give me solution how can i do it 
[image]

```js
<?php
 
 
 echo $_POST['optionval'][0];
 echo $_POST['optionoth'][0];   
 echo $_POST['date'][0];
 echo $_POST['Num'][0];
 echo $_POST['num'][0];
 echo $_POST['optionval'][2];
 echo $_POST['optionoth'][3];   
 echo $_POST['date'][4];
 echo $_POST['Num'][5];
 echo $_POST['num'][6];
 echo $_POST['optionval'][2];
 echo $_POST['optionoth'][2];   
 echo $_POST['date'][2];
 echo $_POST['Num'][2];
 echo $_POST['num'][2];
 
 $optionval= $_POST['optionval']; // required 
  $optionoth= $_POST['optionoth']; // required 
   $date= $_POST['date']; // required 
  $Num= $_POST['Num']; // required 
  $num= $_POST['num']; // required 


  $email_from = '******@gmail.com';//<== update the email address
 $email_subject = "New Order submission";  
 $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<img src="*******" alt="New Appointment" />';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['optionval']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone No:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['optionoth']) . "</td></tr>";
     $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['date']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone No:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['Num']) . "</td></tr>";
 $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone No:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['num']) . "</td></tr>";
    
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
 
 
 
 $to = "******@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
 $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
 //$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
 $headers .= "CC: *******@gmail.com \r\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 
 //Send the email!
 mail($to,$email_subject,$message,$headers);
 //done. redirect to thank-you page.
 if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
  //echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
 }
 header( 'Location:www.google.com' );
 
 // Function to validate against any email injection attempts
 function IsInjected($str)
 {
   $injections = array('(\n+)',
      '(\r+)',
      '(\t+)',
      '(%0A+)',
      '(%0D+)',
      '(%08+)',
      '(%09+)'
      );
   $inject = join('|', $injections);
   $inject = "/$inject/i";
   if(preg_match($inject,$str))
  {
  return true;
   }
   else
  {
  return false;
   }
 }
 
 
 ?>
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Option</td>
                    <td>Text</td>
                    <td>Num</td>
                   <td>No</td>
                  </tr>             
        </thead>
           <tbody class="row">
             <tr class="row-nt">
                 <td>
                    <select name="optionval[]" class="ceventselect" required="">
                          <option value="option-1" selected="selected">option-1</option>
                          <option value="option-2">option-2</option>
                          <option value="option-3">option-3</option>
                          <option value="option-4">option-4</option>
                         
                      </select>                        
                        <input name="optionoth[]" type="text" class="optionother" style="display: none;margin-top:10px;">
                  </td>
                    <td><input name="date[]" type="text" class="date" required=""></td>
                    <td>
                     <select name="Num[]" class="form_field_box4 valid" required="">
                          <option value="Num-1" selected="selected">Num-1</option>
                          <option value="Num-2">Num-2</option>
                          <option value="Num-3">Num-3</option>
                          <option value="Num-4">Num-4</option>
                          
                      </select>
                    </td>
                  
                    <td>
                     <input name="num[]" type="number" class="boxnum"  required="">
                    
                       
                  </td>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
      </table>
        <button class="add-new-evt">Add Row</button>
        

         <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the name of your form elements from `xyz` to `xyz[]` then you should get an array for each  name which holds your values.

E.g.

```
<input name="date[]" type="text" class="date" value="2014-12-25" required="">
<input name="date[]" type="text" class="date" value="2014-12-24" required="">
```

Should then look like:

```
echo $_POST['date'][0]; //2014-12-25 
echo $_POST['date'][1]; //2014-12-24
```

If every row has the same names without `[]` only the values of the last one will be submited.

Comment: Nice explination. This is also true for uploading multiple files. Use `file[]` as a name for the `input`s or `formdata` entries